# Get property names present in a breeze entity

Tags: properties, breeze

After I execute breeze query as shown below:

```
   var breezeQuery = function(){
    var query = EntityQuery.from('TableA')
                   .inlineCount();

        function querySuceeded(data) {
               //data.results[0] contains the entity
        }

        manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySuceeded)
    }
```

I get the entity in data.results[0] which contains properties as well as other information like entityAspect etc.
How can I get the property names present in a breeze entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *MetadataStore*.  Something like this:

```
var tableAType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("TableA");
var dataProperties = tableAType.dataProperties;
var navigationProperties = tableAType.navigationProperties;
```

or from an instance of a entity ( not a projection), since every entity will have an 'entityType' property you can also do this:

```
var tableAType = tableAInstance.entityType;
var dataProperties = tableAType.dataProperties;
var navigationProperties = tableAType.navigationProperties;
```

Also see: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityType.html

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys(data.result[0])` is the vanilla JavaScript way to get all properties of the `data.result[0]` object. Just saying.

Jay's way of course winnows those down to the properties monitored by Breeze, the persisted properties in particular. That's probably what you meant :-)